# Which way is SO submitting the questions?

Tags: discussion, form-submit

Directly submit the form

Or by ajax?

The process is too far for me to distinguish.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, it is a good old HTTP POST, and it invokes `/questions/ask/submit`.

Answer (score 2):

Normal HTML Form. StackOverflow is intended to work without JavaScript enabled, so no *critical* functions are JavaScript.

Comment: If by critical you mean only asking and answering questions. Everything else is pretty ajaxified including the voting controls and all of the moderator controls. Makes using the site an absolute nightmare (or near impossibility) when you get served a bad JS file or for some reason your corporate firewall/content filter starts blocking it for no reason. *Speaking from sad panda experience*

Comment: True, but I only consider Asking and Answering critical :) All the other stuff is important (especially for moderators), but the main function on the site is usable to Non-JS users

Comment: @Michael Stum: it would be trivial to make the voting work with just a post, and gain would be significant for a small part of the user base.

Comment: How would a "small part of the user base" benefit from being able to vote even with JavaScript disabled. Maybe the community would benefit from having even more votes, but they wouldn't really.

Comment: @TheTXI: I so want to start rating software on the "Sad Panda Experience" scale.